# Exporting data from C# to Excel version error

Tags: c#, excel

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library but I am getting this error:

> Error CS0433
> The type 'Application' exists in both 'Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, removing the reference to Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel made the error go away.